# Bootstrap datetimepicker - stepping from a given time

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have two datetimepickers, one for hour of departure and one for hour of arrival.

What I'd like to do is make it so that the arrival time is always a modulo of 6 of the departure time. For example, if the departure time is 13:40, the available options for the arrival time would be 13:46, 13:52, 13:58 and so on.

It seems that bootstrap's datetimepicker only allows stepping from the hour only (13:00, 14:00, 15:00 ...) and not for a given minute.

Is there a way to allow stepping from a given hour + minute ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What datetimepicker are you using? (what is the link to the js...)  There are several and I want to make sure I'm looking at the right one before giving an answer.  I like http://www.daterangepicker.com/ and what you are wanting to do is simple - other 'pickers' aren't as flexible or may not have the feature at all, so it is important to know what you are working with.

Comment: I've been using [bootstrap's datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker), but i'd be happy to switch if I have to

Answer (score 1):

1. the picker you are using states "We are in code freeze and this
   issue tracker is no longer actively monitored" - not something I
   would recommend for a new project......
2. in considering what you are doing (unless you have something else
   going on that you didn't put in your question - adding your code and
   more detail of what you are doing might be needed....), it sounds
   like you want to select one date+time and have an automatic
   'arrival' selector set.

   I would suggest you consider using the date/time picker (of your
   choice, though see '1' above.....) and a SELECT for the arrival time
   (this may not fit your application though since you didn't say if
   arrival can/may be a different day, I'm presuming them on the same
   date and going the 'easier' way..... :)

   In the 'onchange' of the picker, you can create/update (more likely
   update) a select dropdown to have the times you like (in your case
   modulo 6).

   This is a simpler solution as well as being a more user friendly one
   (IMHO)
3. You can use something like [daterangepicker.com](http://daterangepicker.com%20daterangepicker.com) and set the 'timePickerIncrement' (or equivalent if you use some other picker).

If you use daterangepicker.com, you can try using a function for the timePickerIncrement (to get modulo 6), or it may only allow selection in minutes (after I reread the docs, this does seem to be the case...)  If this is the case, then I would look at 'isInvalidDate'.  You can set the function to only allow modulo 6 of the start date to be valid (do a search on the page for 'isInvalidDate' there are some good tips there for coding this).

That should get you where you need to be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I managed to do what I wanted by editing the decrementMinutes / incrementMinutes functions of bootstrap's datetimepicker.